# SQL Query to retrive data from two tables from below situation

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I am having two table table A and table B in MySQL database and i want a output from both of them column,
            table A columns a_id integer(5),a_name varchar(20).
            table B columns b_id integer(5),b_name varchar(20),a_id varchar(10).

```
        And tables records are,
        select * from a;                
        +------+--------+
        | a_id | a_name |
        +------+--------+
        |    1 | a1     |
        |    2 | a2     |
        +------+--------+

        select * from b;            
        +------+--------+------+
        | b_id | b_name | a_id |
        +------+--------+------+
        |    1 | b1     | 1,2  |
        |    2 | b2     | 1    |
        |    3 | b3     | null |
        +------+--------+------+

        Now i want to get data which are in b table but also
        with a_name column,         
        +------+--------+-------+
        | b_id | b_name | a_name|
        +------+--------+-------+
        |    1 | b1     | a1,a2 |
        |    2 | b2     | a1    | 
        |    3 | b3     | null  | 
        +------+--------+-------+
```

How to achieve this output i have tried with join but not get proper      result.is there any aggregate function which can combine a1,a2 value and return in row.any help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: You need to normalize the 2nd table, and if this you cant do with the existing schema, then checkout `left join with find_in_set`

Comment: yes join will give 3 records with null value but that value a1,a2 for first row how to get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do that, however you should normalize the table `b` and do not store comma separated values.

```
select
b.b_id,
b.b_name,
group_concat(a.a_name) as a_name
from b
left join a on find_in_set(a.a_id,b.a_id) > 0
group by b.b_id
```